# Divide HTML page into resizable areas using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you help me with the name of a plugin for jQuery or an approach that I can follow to divide my HTML page to resizable areas just like in this website
[www.trirand.com](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqform/)

Where if you resized an area it will affect the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at jQuery UI Resizable ?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Comment: I mentioned above above that if I resized an area I wont the other adjacent areas to be affected relatively